# Knex - how to determine query that failed during transaction

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am working with Knex to write a simple transaction. I am inserting an object into one table and then insert an array of objects. Since I am using Knex in my API, I would like to know which insert failed. Unfortunately the error objects only shares this information:

```
{
"length":130,
 "name":"error",
 "severity":\"ERROR\",
 "code":\"22P02\",
 "file":\"uuid.c\",
 "line":\"137\",
 "routine":\"string_to_uuid\"
}
```

I would like to know though which query exactly failed to send back a proper error message to the Frontend. I am using a lambda setup with a RDS connection.

This is my transaction:

```
  const test = await client.transaction(async (trx) => {
    try {
      await trx<any>('schema.table')
        .insert({
          id: answers.myId,
          addition: 'some text',
        });
      const test = answers.answers.map((answer) => ({
        id: answer.id,
        my_id: answers.myId,
        offered_answer_id: answer.offered_answer_id,
        value: answer.value !== '' ? answer.value : null,
      }));
      await trx<any>('schema.table2').insert(test);
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
```

I am triggering an error by manipulating an uuid. So the error object is technically correct but I cannot figure out which insert caused it with this information.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Just add debug print between each query and you will see which one threw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I am looking for a solution to return the error query and not only view it in the console.

Comment: Then you probably need to catch the error add information about failed query and throw it again. Also enabling long stack traces might help. Problem here is that when database throws an error, knex doesn't touch it. If DB driver doesn't include the information about the query in the error then the information won't be there.